# Create different contents in one page

Tags: php

I have a php page named `test.php`. I want to make different contents in this page:

When the user (manually) navigates to `test.php?id=1` the script needs to show:
`echo "one";`

When the user (manually) navigates to `test.php?id=2` the script needs to show:
`echo "two";`

There are no POST or GET functions for this page. And I dont think it needs it. The user will enter the URL of the page and the script will show the content for the `?id=` that is entered by the user.

I found some examples on the internet, but in this scripts the script was getting the `?id=` (case) from the script and not from the URL.

My question is. How can I make these pages and specify the content for each of these pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is pretty vague, but I'll answer it the best I know how.

Any url with ?[variable]=[value] has a get variable, and must be handled like so.

A pretty easy way to do what you're asking would be to do something like

```
<?php
$page = $_GET['id'];
switch($page){
  case '1':
    echo 'one';
    break;
  case '2':
    echo 'two';
    break;
}
?>
```

but to get variables from the url, you have to use a get variable.